Making object on canvas take action corresponding to 2d list
I have a matrix consisting of 0 and 1, where 0 is an empty area and 1 is an obstacle. I've made a canvas with colored squares according to each value in the matrix, forming a grid. I also have a circle which is meant to travel right or left normally, and will move up or down if a obstacle is in front to avoid it.
How do I get the object to move according to the values in the matrix? I can't understand it.
Code for reference:
#generate an eviornemnt, represented by Tkinter, consisting of
    #a matrix representing the room
    #1 and 0 will denote the presence of obstacles

import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

ROOM_WIDTH = 700
ROOM_HEIGHT = 700
SPACE_SIZE = 75
OBSTACLE_COLOR = "#ADD8E6"
FREE_COLOR = "#90EE90"

rows = 4
columns = 4

window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, height=ROOM_HEIGHT, width=ROOM_WIDTH)

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True
        self.x = ROOM_WIDTH // 8
        self.y = ROOM_HEIGHT // 8
        self.my_circle = canvas.create_oval(self.x, self.y, self.x + 30, self.y + 30)
        canvas.moveto(self.my_circle, 30, 40)

    def left(self, event):
        x = -8
        y = 0
        canvas.move(self.my_circle, x, y)

    def right(self):
        x = 8
        y = 0
        canvas.move(self.my_circle, x, y)

    def up(self):
        x = 0
        y = -8
        canvas.move(self.my_circle, x, y)

    def down(self, event):
        x = 0
        y = 8
        canvas.move(self.my_circle, x, y)

    def move_lawnmower(self):
        # use math: calculate the distance covered in a square and use it to determine when to move

        # check cell for corresponding matrix value
                #cell_value = matrix[i][j]

                # Perform the movement
                bot.right()

                # Schedule the next movement after 50 milliseconds
                window.after(200, self.move_lawnmower)

                # Stop the movement after 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)
                window.after(5000, self.stop)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False


class Environment:
        def draw_matrix(matrix, canvas):
        # loop through matrix, assign color depending on value and create square
            for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
                for j, item in enumerate(row):
                    x1, y1 = j * SPACE_SIZE, i * SPACE_SIZE
                    x2, y2 = (j+1) * SPACE_SIZE, (i+1) * SPACE_SIZE
                    color = OBSTACLE_COLOR if item == 1 else FREE_COLOR
                    canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=color)

window.title("Robot lawnmower")
window.resizable(False, False)

Environment.draw_matrix(matrix, canvas)

bot = Bot()  # Create an instance of the Bot class

# Bind the event handlers to the window
    # window.bind('<Left>', bot.left)
    # window.bind('<Right>', bot.right)
    # window.bind('<Up>', bot.up)
    # window.bind('<Down>', bot.down)

canvas.pack()

bot.move_lawnmower()

window.mainloop()


Thank you.
